# Find equivalent resistance at terminals a-b and c-d in the given circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, circuits

[image: Picture of the circuit]

I tried delta-wye transformation, which hasn't worked for me. Plus, I don't understand how to solve for two different pair of terminals, all problems before this had only one pair of terminals.

Comment: Hint: For a-b, pretend c-d and the 60 Ohm aren't there, and the opposite for c-d.

Comment: Hint: You shouldn't use delta-wye transformation. Just look at what is in parallel and what is in series. Redraw the schematic for a-b and for c-d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you a couple of hints. To find the equivalent resistance between a and b you you can neglect the 60-ohm resistor as it's left open. In this case, the 15, (right) 100, and 150 ohm-resistors are all in series, and the result is in parallel with the left 100-ohm resistor, and whole thing comes in series with the 50-ohm resistor. This is for a and b terminals. Repeat the same steps for equivalent resistance between terminals c and d. \end

Answer (score 0):

case 1: when voltage applied across AB, no current at  60ohm resistor, so it can be neglected.
and solve the remaining circuit using series and parallel method.
150+100+150=400ohm
50+(400.100)/400+100 = 130 ohm =Rab
case 2:when voltage applied across CD, no current at  50ohm resistor, so it can be neglected.
and solve the remaining circuit using series and parallel method.
150+100+150=400ohm
60+(400.100)/400+100 = 120 ohm =Rcd..

Comment: There is only one 150 ohm in the circuit :)